# Maven ignoring build segment in settings.xml?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have the following profile in my settings.xml:

```
        <profile>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <properties>
                <gpg.passphrase>secretKey</gpg.passphrase>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

The gpg.passphrase property is accessible just fine from my pom.xml, but when I try to do `mvn release:prepare`, the GPG-task doesn't get executed.
Using Maven 3.6.0.

The settings.xml path is set correctly, because I can access the property and other properties inside the settings.xml work just fine. And of course, the profile is under my active profiles, too:

```
    <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>ossrh</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

Comment: "mvn release:prepare" executes a goal of a plugin, the gpg plugin is bound only to a phase, so you need to run "mvn verify" or a later phase (like install or deploy).

Comment: @wemu No, I tried those,too. All of them don't work either

Comment: indeed you are correct. You cant add that to your settings file: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html (section: Which areas of a POM can be customized by each type of profile? Why?)

Comment: I just read that, too. I finally fixed my problem right now by adding the profile to my pom.xml, not my settings.xml. If you write an answer to my question, I will upvote you anyway and approve your answer