# Maven settings.xml to include build tag properties

Tags: maven, build, directory, settings, profile

According to *http://maven.apache.org/settings.html* we have an example and explanation of all the elements.

But I want, for example, customize some build settings for ALL projects, not to be pushed in every project **pom.xml**.

Other people looking for this, too, but still no solution.

[Maven ignoring build segment in settings.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541511/maven-ignoring-build-segment-in-settings-xml)

But, surprisingly, ***build*** tag is NOT available in **settings.xml**.

Is there a way to inject build parameters, like target dir into settings.xml using profiles, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- The standard way is to create a company parent POM that is used as parent for all the projects. It can configure plugins and other build information.
- If you want things be overridden by the `settings.xml`, use properties and then define the properties in the `settings.xml`.

Comment: Could you provide an working example SSCCE way customising project build dir via profile?

Comment: Usually I would not customise the project build Dir. It should be `/target`. I do not unterstand why one should use a profile to change the build dir. Furthermore: If you want to know something more specific please ask a new question.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier - I just don't want to pollute my source folders with build artefacts, which is considered quite a habit and normal practice thou. I can customize it easily at project level, but I I'd rather do some things globally, as well as other build options. If you have an idea how to do it, you may tell us here.

Comment: You don't pollute your source folders (`src`), you build into your `target` directory. This is the Maven standard and what everybody does.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier, I want it to be customized some way for my projects globally via say, profile, not parent pom.xml. But it's hardcoded. No good. If you know, how to do it, please share.

Comment: @WebComer Sorry, I cannot follow you. As I said: You should not change the `target` dir.